# C# re-using SQLCommand

Tags: c#, sql

How do I reuse a SQLCommand for say multiple queries?

e.g

```
SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("SElect * from BKLAH", myConnection);
mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now I want to use mycommand again but use a different SQL query.  How would I do this?

Comment: But I would like to understand why?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight has given you the answer, however to use it seems somewhat pointless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set `CommandText` property of your command, like this:

```
mycommand.CommandText = @"UPDATE BKLAH SET a = 5 WHERE id=@id";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use it in a `USING` section.

Command 1:

```
using (SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("SElect * from BKLAH", myConnection))
{
mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Command 2:

```
using (SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("SElect * from BKLAH2", myConnection))
{
mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: While I completely agree this is what you should do, that's not reusing mycommand.

Comment: Exactly. But personally, reusing the same SqlCommand is not a good practice, even it's doable.

Comment: Wholehearted agreement, have to be a very specific circumstance, as you effectively you'll be persisting the connection as well, which except for very rare circumstances is a really bad idea in ADO.Net